# #define macro outside class

Tags: c++, macros

I do not quite understand this usage of macros here:

In Dog.cpp, there is this outside the class scope:

```
BEGIN_SETPARAM_MAP(Dog)
    MAP_SETPARAM(eParam_Macro_Eat,      Eat)
    MAP_SETPARAM(eParam_Macro_Walk,     Walk)
    MAP_SETPARAM(eParam_Macro_Sleep,    Sleep)
END_GETPARAM_MAP(Dog)
```

And in Animals.h there is this a macro definition, also found outside the Animal class scope:

```
class Animal
{
protected:
   HRESULT  MapSetParamHandler(ULONG paramId, ParamValueHandler handler);
   virtual void SetupSetParamMap(void) {}
};

#define BEGIN_SETPARAM_MAP(className)   void className::SetupSetParamMap(void) {typedef className ThisClass;
#define MAP_SETPARAM(paramId, handler)  MapSetParamHandler(paramId, static_cast<ParamValueHandler>(&ThisClass::handler));
#define END_SETPARAM_MAP(className)     }
```

I don't understand how this actually works.  Why is it allowed to re-define the method `SetupSetParamMap()` outside the class?  If so, will this override the implementation on the Animal class?

I have no idea how the code above compiles just fine.

I tried creating a simpler example but I am getting a syntax error:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Animal
{
    public:
    void cuddle()
    {
        std::cout << "Cuddle" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
    public:
    void bark()
    {
        std::cout << "Bark" << std::endl;
        cuddle();
    }
    virtual void sleep(){}
};

#define BEGIN_SETPARAM_MAP(className) void Dog::sleep() \
{ \
    std::cout << "sleep" << std::endl; \
} 

BEGIN_SETPARAM_MAP(Dog);

int main()
{
    Dog dog;
    dog.bark();
    dog.sleep();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error:

```
25:44: error: redefinition of 'void Dog::sleep()'
30:1: note: in expansion of macro 'BEGIN_SETPARAM_MAP'
22:18: note: 'virtual void Dog::sleep()' previously defined here
```

Help, anyone??

Comment: You haven't shown the `dog.h` header that goes with your first working example.

Comment: The class Animal declares the member function SetupSetParamMap ,while the macro defines (gives an implementation) it. Your code defines a member twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand how this actually works. Why is it allowed to re-define the method SetupSetParamMap() outside the class?

The code works simply because it is not defining the method Animal::SetupSetParamMap. What the macro does is allow you to implement SomeDerivedAnimalType::SetupSetParamMap for another object type. If you attempted to do: BEGIN_SETPARAM_MAP(Animal), then now you would have a redefinition error for Animal::SetupSetParamMap. However BEGIN_SETPARAM_MAP(Sheep) would not cause a problem.

wrt to the second code example, the compiler error is pretty self explanatory...  (and you clearly have identified it!)

```cpp
class Dog : public Animal
{
    public:
    void bark()
    {
        std::cout << "Bark" << std::endl;
        cuddle();
    }
    virtual void sleep(){}  ///< I AM THE IMPLEMENTATION OF Dog::sleep
};

/// I AM ALSO THE IMPLEMENTATION OF Dog::sleep, and therefore an error... 
#define BEGIN_SETPARAM_MAP(className) void Dog::sleep() \
{ \
    std::cout << "sleep" << std::endl; \
}
```

Here's a slightly simpler example for you to get your head around ;)

```cpp
class Animal
{
    public:

    /// I need to be implemented for each animal
    /// It's boiler-plate repetition, so lets macro this
    virtual void speak() = 0;
};

// use within the class definition to add capabilities
#define CAN_SPEAK(animalType) void speak() override;

// use to implement the boiler plate code of the method
#define MAKE_SPEAK(animalType, noise) void animalType::speak() \
{ \
    std::cout << noise << std::endl; \
} 

// here's a dog that says woof
class Dog : public Animal
{
    public:
    CAN_SPEAK(Dog)
};
MAKE_SPEAK(Dog, "woof")

// ... and a sheep that says baa
class Sheep : public Animal
{
    public:
    CAN_SPEAK(Sheep)
};
MAKE_SPEAK(Sheep, "baa")

int main()
{
  std::vector<Animal*> animals;
  animals.push_back(new Dog);
  animals.push_back(new Sheep); 
  for(auto animal : animals)
  {
    animal->speak();
  }

  /* yes, I should be freeing the memory here... */

  return 0;
}
```